# How to use API and JSON Correctly?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a bot that is built with botkit and using a Zendesk api to pull information.

I have a function that asks a user for a search term and the bot searches relevant information about that search term. It pulls the information from the Zendesk API and outputs the answer.

I don't understand when accessing the object's value some values are able to be outputted while some are not.

For example, if the user submits 'jim' as the search term. I can pull relevant information by doing this: tickets[0].id  + tickets[0].priority + tickets[0].subject + tickets[0].description.

When I do something like this: 
tickets[4]- I get undefined values.

The full code of what I'm trying to do is this:

```
    controller.hears(['SEARCH TICKET',/search ticket/gi,  /^.{0,}jirabot.
{0,}$/],
   ['direct_message','direct_mention','mention','ambient'],function(bot,message) 
{

  // start a conversation to handle this response.
  bot.startConversation(message,function(err,convo) {

convo.ask('What are you looking for?',function(response,convo) {

  zendesk.search.list('query='+response.text+'&sort_by=priority&sort_order=desc').then(function(tickets){

  console.log(tickets);
bot.reply(message, 'The Ticket ID Number: ' + tickets[3] + tickets[0].id + '\n The Ticket Priority: ' + tickets[0].priority + '\n The Ticket Subject: ' + tickets[0].subject + '\n The Ticket Description: \n'+ tickets[0].description + '\n');
convo.next();
}
    });

 });

});

});
```

Here is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
"results": [(in here is the information like ticket subject, priority, id, 
etc.],
"facets": null,
"next_page": null,
"previous_page": null,
"count": 2
}
```

How do I get the value for count? I get undefined when I do tickets[4].

Comment: `Here is what the JSON looks like` - how is that related to `tickets[0].id + tickets[0].priority + tickets[0].subject + tickets[0].description`

Comment: within the results array, I can do tickets[0].id to get a value. So, I'm able to get any value within the first element of the tickets array, but for some reason I just get undefined when I do tickets[4].

Comment: perhaps there's only 4 results? i.e. 0, 1, 2 and 3 - the most important part of the response is the part you haven't shown, ironically

Comment: What is it that you wanna see? The JSON shows 4 elements - 0, 1, 2, 3 ,4 (results, facets, next_page, previous_page, and count).

Comment: `The JSON shows 4 elements - 0, 1, 2, 3 ,4` really? you think so? no, it shows 5 for a start, and they aren't `0,1,2,3,4` they are `results, facets, next_page, previous_page, count`

Comment: `tickets` is an object, not array.

Comment: Okay, but doing tickets.count doesn't return anything?

Comment: then what you have shown is not what the json representation of `tickets` is, or you are trying to access it outside of the callback

Answer (score 0):

To access the properties of the JSON you've shown, you wouldn't use index values like 0,1,2,3. Instead you'd write `ticket["results"]`, `ticket["count"]`, `ticket["<PropNameHere>"]`